# how to find indices in cell array

Tags: matlab

I have  a vector, size: `normal(494020);`

```
normal={ 'back.' 'buffer_overflow.'  'ftp_write.'  'guess_passwd.' 'imap.'};
```

The strings in this vector are randomly distributed. I want to know what is the index of `'back.'` , and how many indices it covers. Same way for other strings. Please help.

Comment: That's a bit fortran-y way of specifying the size of an array.... And what do you mean "how many indices it cover"?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp` to compare a cell array of strings with a string:

```
>> normal={ 'back.' 'buffer_overflow.' 'ftp_write.' 'guess_passwd.' 'imap.'};
>> strcmp('back.',normal)

ans =

     1     0     0     0     0
```

So what you're after is

```
string='back.';
index_of_string=find(strcmp(string,normal),1);
```

this will return the first index `k` for which `normal{k}` is the same as `string`. So it will discard multiplicities.

If by "*how many indices it cover*" you mean that you need multiplicities, then just remove the `,1` from the call to `find`, then you'll get an index *vector* containing every index `k` for which `normal{k}` is equal to `string`.